# Why wxWidgets cannot be found during compiling openbabel?

Tags: wxwidgets, openbabel

I am trying to install openbabel-2.4.1 in my centos 7 system. The the cmake command (cmake ..) gives information that wxWidgets and  Eigen cannot be found:

```
-- Using included inchi library.
-- Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES) 
-- Checking available shared pointer...
-- Use std::tr1::shared_ptr in tr1/memory
-- Could NOT find Eigen3 (missing: EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR EIGEN3_VERSION_OK) (Required is at least version "2.91.0")
-- Could NOT find Eigen2 (missing: EIGEN2_INCLUDE_DIR EIGEN2_VERSION_OK) (Required is at least version "2.0.0")
-- Checking for module 'cairo'
--   No package 'cairo' found
-- Could NOT find Cairo (missing: CAIRO_LIBRARIES CAIRO_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
-- Could NOT find Cairo. PNG output will NOT be supported.
-- Attempting to build the GUI
--    wxWidgets not found => GUI will not be built
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/sunyp/software/openbabel/openbabel-2.4.1/build
```

Actually I have installed wxWidgets-3.1.2 and EIGEN3 and add their lib path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, but why they cannot be found by cmake? And how to solve the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you comppile it yourself, or install from the repository? If the former - did you run `make install`? If you run `which wx-config` what will be the output?

Comment: The ccp program installed in my system contains a wx-config executable. The command "wx-config" gives: "~software/ccp4/ccp4-7.0/bin". After commenting out the ccp executable environment variable, wxWidgets library can be found when running cmake for openbabel. But is there a way not commenting out the ccp executable environment variable but cmake still can find the  wxWidgets library so that the ccp program can still be used?

Comment: Now the running cmake gives the following information:                                         
-- Could NOT find Eigen3 (missing: EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR EIGEN3_VERSION_OK) (Required is at least version "2.91.0")
-- Could NOT find Eigen2 (missing: EIGEN2_INCLUDE_DIR EIGEN2_VERSION_OK) (Required is at least version "2.0.0")                                             The EIGEN3 has been installed and its pkgconfig directory has been added to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable. Then why cmake cannot find EIGEN3?

Comment: what is ccp? And you didn't answer my questions, in particular - how did you install wxWidgets? Did you compile it yourself or installed from the repository? And if the former - what configure command was used?

Comment: ccp4 is a biological program (http://www.ccp4.ac.uk). There is wxWidgets excutives, such as wxrc in its bin directory. I compiled wxWidget from source (wxWidgets-3.1.2.tar.bz2 downloaded from wxwidgets.org/downloads) myself. The configure command was:./configure --with-gtk --enable-unicode --disable-shared prefix=~/software/wxWidgets/wxWidgets-3.1.2-install

Comment: I can't help with Eigen3, sorry. You need to ask on either OpenBabel or Eigen froums/ML. I hope wxWidgets issue is resolved.

Comment: The problem of eigen3 can be address by add -DEIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR option to cmake.